# D3 Horizontal Bar chart with positive and negative values and height of bar set from data

Tags: d3.js, charts

I would like to be able to do a bar chart like this Variable width bar chart with matching, data driven, variable width but as a horizontal bar chart, with both negative and positive values on the x-axis and the height of the bars to be proportional to a function of the whole and have the y-axis scale accordingly.

Example of output:
[image: Example of output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script>
  // Data 
  const data = [{
      x: -5,
      y: 15,
      color: '#ff0000'
    }, // 15%
    {
      x: 7,
      y: 55,
      color: '#0000ff'
    }, // 55%
    {
      x: 3,
      y: 30,
      color: '#00ff00'
    }, // 30% 
  ];
  // Dimensions
  const width = 500;
  const height = 300;
  const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  };
  // X scale
  const x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.min(data, d => d.x * 1.25), d3.max(data, d => d.x * 1.25)]).range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
  // Y scale 
  const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);
  // SVG
  const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
  // Bars
  svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).enter().append('rect').attr('x', d => x(Math.min(0, d.x))).attr('y', d => y(d.y)).attr('width', d => Math.abs(x(d.x) - x(0))).attr('height', d => y(0) - y(d.y)).attr('fill', d => d.color);
  // Axes
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5).tickFormat(d => d + '%');
  // Draw axes
  svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`).call(xAxis);
  svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`).call(yAxis);
</script>
</html>
```